# If using glue on shower panels instead of tile, how do you cover and seal the 1/4 inch gap between cement board and tub flange

Tags: bathtub, cement-board

I know cement board is installed about 1/4 inch above tub flange. The tile will cover gap. But if we aren’t using tile and just using the thin glue on panels?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's supposed to be with tile; if you're still using backer board, it should be similar--you'll just have your panel instead of tile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cement board is actually supposed to be installed over the tub flange.

I apply [Polyurethane caulk](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tremco-10-1-oz-Buff-Vulkem-116-Exterior-Polyurethane-Sealant-7103012/203369939?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D24-024_002_CAULKS-NA-Multi-NA-PLALIA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FY21_Sundries_PLALIA_&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D24-024_002_CAULKS-NA-Multi-NA-PLALIA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FY21_Sundries_PLALIA_-71700000074808981-58700006445316099-92700058237758740&gclid=CjwKCAjwyNSoBhA9EiwA5aYlb42saFkGCumJgSLgsqzMX4ijyXiJ5xqodUPiB8IXcXCebObOqMrvVRoC_3MQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)to the flange before installing the backer board.  I like polyurethane to silicone because other things can stick to poly and it can be painted if needed unlike silicone.

Rather than remove the backer and reinstall, I would apply [seam seal](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-89-in-x-165-ft-Seam-Tape-100000040752/306575250?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D22-022_004_INSULATION-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-4035567-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-Pmax-CL3TestA&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D22-022_004_INSULATION-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-4035567-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-Pmax-CL3TestA-71700000103694443--&gclid=CjwKCAjwyNSoBhA9EiwA5aYlb1nGHHAXqSZs8y_7kVCcyvUeJwfmTyD0PnkWtBMXCY3jIcyYlviKJRoCl1kQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) over the 1/4 gap and tub flange then the polyurethane caulk  to the taped tub flange and install the panels.

Use the recommended caulk ( usually silicone) to seal the seams of the panels.